# Is it Possible to install evernote on Ubuntu using Fogger?

Tags: 12.04, webapps, evernote

I found that, there is not official client of Evernote for Ubuntu. Many people use Everpad on Ubuntu to synchronize Evennote with Ubuntu desktop, but I'm interested to make the Evernote Web into an web apps for Ubuntu using Fogger?

Is it possible?

Comment: Mentioned answer completely , have a look.

Comment: I have created Ask Ubuntu also using Fogger. OMG! its really cool. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install Fogger and that will have a way around to turn evernote

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:loneowais/fogger
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fogger
```

and its so easy. Just choose the option `create a new fog app` Then you will get prompt as 
[image]

Type URL as : www.evernote.com

Name: your wish ( usually Evernote)

Then just type as Evernote in Unity dash and you will get it.

[image]

**I have done some work around using fogger.**

- If I opened Evernote in Xubuntu with Fogger , it has taken almost 60 MB of RAM to run even it is Idle.
- If I opened Gmail in Xubuntu with Fogger , It has taken almost 220 MB of RAM and I do not recommended such usage. So if any body would like to create Gmail Fogger , my suggestion is dont go for it.you can save plenty of RAM with browser.
- Ask Ubuntu @Xubuntu with Fogger has taken 120 MB RAM.

Comment: I tried this a long time ago and was completely dissatisfied because it couldn't run in offline mode. So, it is pretty much useless. Also thanks for posting the RAM usage.